# What's causing the "stalled" gap when loading resources in my developer tools?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, google-chrome

Between the document loading and my first script, I have a strange gap where nothing happens.

Hovering over the resource "style.css", tells me a stalled time of 98ms.

At this point my async scripts and style.css all load at the same time.

This is the wordpress `style.css` and I'm using `wp_enqueue_script()` loading them asynchronously.

Here's a screenshot of my results:
[image]

What generally causes "stalled" instances on web pages, just so I have a general idea of where to look?